# JoinField_management - error 000339: OIDs missing

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins

I am trying to join a csv-attribute table to a shapefile based on a variable ("pct16").

This is my code:

```
path_shp = cd + "ArcGIS/"
path_data = cd + "data/2016/raw/"
arcpy.JoinField_management(path_shp + "voting_precincts.shp", "pct16", path_data + "all_precinct_results.csv", "pct16")
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> ERROR 000339: Input C:/.../raw/all_precinct_results.csv does not have
>   OIDs

The [ESRI help](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00326-00350-000339.htm) advices to add an OID column to the table. My question is, how do I do that in ArcPy? Or, are there any quicker alternatives for my purpose?

A question that seems to be related is [Working around Table does not contain OIDs arcpy Error 000339?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188825). Maybe, it contains useful information to solve my problem but I was not able to judge for myself because I did not understand the question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [Copy Rows](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-rows.htm) arcpy function (same tool you'd use in ArcToolbox) and turn your csv into a table (with OIDs) before joining. Give this a shot:

```
path_shp = cd + "ArcGIS/"
path_data = cd + "data/2016/raw/"

arcpy.CopyRows_management("Test.csv", "all_precinct_results")    
arcpy.JoinField_management(path_shp + "voting_precincts.shp", "pct16", path_data + "all_precinct_results", "pct16")
```

After you run this code, take a look inside your folder in ArcCatalog, refresh the view, and see that the new table with OIDs has been created.